# grails 2.2.1 need to upgrade log4j

Tags: grails, log4j

I've searched hi and low for the answer but still can't get anything to work. I am on an air-gapped system and don't have access to outside repositories but i can get jars imported. I need to upgrad log4j on my grails 2.2.1 version (can't be updated) to at least log4j v2.17.2. I've tried the setting my dependencies to the new version and adding the new jar to my lib dir so the compile can pick them up. i've also tried removing the old version at the bottom of the buildconfig.groovy. While the dependency SEEMS to work, removing the old version causes an error on compile.

Can someone point me to the proper way to update log4j on this version of grails?

builconfig.groovy contains

```
dependecies {
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.2'
}
and at bottom
grails.war.resources = {stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar")
}
```

i NEED to get the old version out of there so that my security scanners stop flaggin

Comment: This is not an answer to your question just as an FYI, we releaed Grails 2.2.1 10 years ago this month.  I _think_ log4j 2.17.2 was released about a year ago.  The Grails team has not done any testing with that combination and maybe it is worth trying, but I would be a little surprised if that all works. Best of luck!

Comment: our team spent some time on this, and they got logging working, but only the default config.  They couldn't get the config being read by Grails startup to actually be applied to the log4J v2 logger.

Comment: Thanks for the info. While working on this I managed to somehow completely clean out the project such that it erased all the grails classes. now they won't rebuild and the project won't start. I've tried cleaning, refreshing dependencies (which appears to work) and rebuilding. the project keeps failing with errors like the below
unable to resolve class grails.pludin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler.CacheConfigGrailsClass
it looks like the .groovy files are there but the class isn't getting built

Comment: does anyone have an answer for this? even if it's not an upgrade to the latest version how would i go about upgrading to a newer version and removing the old? or is there a way to just remove log4j completely?